# Stopping an email send using RaiseError function

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have written code like this to stop email send using the RaiseError function.  Does this work without giving True?

```
SET @Created_Date = Created_Date 
IF @Created_Date > "6/30/2022 11:59:00 PM" THEN 
 RaiseError('Voucher Date Expired') 
ENDIF
```

does this stops email send ??

Comment: It depends on how the `Created_Date` field in your DE is formatted, you need to make sure it’s the same format as the expression used in the second line. I’d add a [FormatDate](https://ampscript.guide/formatdate/) function to both dates to make sure the are formatted the same way.

Comment: If the date criteria is true this will also stop the entire send if you're batching the emails.  Using `true` for the [second a parameter](https://ampscript.guide/raiseerror) will skip only the current subscriber.